# Change object to its subclass in swift

Tags: swift, oop

I have a model object User:

```
class User: NSObject {
    var idUser = 0
    var email = ""
    var name = ""
}
```

Then I have UserViewController, where I want to display users in table:

```
class UserViewController: UIViewController {
    var users = [User]()
}
```

But I need some additional flags (properties) and calculated properties on User object:

```
class UserWrap: User {
    var checked: Bool {
        get {
            return // some calculations
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to use this subclass object (UserWrap) in UserViewController:

```
class UserViewController: UIViewController {
    var users = [UserWrap]()
}
```

Model function getUsers returns [User]?:

```
func getUsers() -> [User]? {
    return // data from DB
}
```

What is the correct approach to handle this (have UserWrap objects instead of User in controller users property)?

1. Should model returns UserWrap object instead of User?
2. Should I "remap" those Users returned from model when storing them to controller property?
3. Should I add those additional properties / calculated properties directly to User object and don't use UserWrap at all?

Comment: There's no genuine approach for this. The way you want to do is the right way. Just consider if there's redundant complicity inside your approach. I believe you have a good reason to use `UserWrap` for the moment, but I don't see why you need it with the information you gave us. So I'll pick #3 if I must.

Comment: If DB returns objects of kind `[UserWrap]` , I think it is most correctly to update your in app model. So you can update your ViewController's `users` property to the correct Object type too. This way there would be no unnecessary casting and your code would be much clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @sCha I want to store model unrelated information in there, like if the object is "selected" in table view for further processing (checked).